# jQuery: After all elements are clicked, modify another

Tags: jquery

What I know about jQuery is very basic, so bear with me.

I have a table listing several images/thumbnails and each thumbnail has the functionality of zooming in and out. There's also two buttons for "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" on top of the table in case the user wants to enlarge/shrink all images instead of doing it one by one.

So far I have accomplished being able to:

- Click on each thumbnail and zoom in/out
- Click on the Zoom In button and have all thumbnails enlarge
- Click on the Zoom Out button and have all thumbnails shrink

What I'm having problems with is:

A. *Deactivate* the Zoom In button when all thumbnails have been individually zoomed in; then *activate* the Zoom Out button.

B. *Deactivate* the Zoom Out button when all thumbnails have been individually zoomed out; then *activate* the Zoom In button.

I think this can be accomplished with `.length()`, but I just can't wrap my head around the logic.

I tried this but of course it doesn't work:

```
$('a.zoom-trigger.shrink').length(function(){
  $('.zin').toggleClass('active');
  $('.zout').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here's a ***[Demo in Codepen](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/vFzwA)***.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT--**

In the demo I used 3 elements but in reality the amount of elements in the table is unknown since all the data is coming from a Data Base.

---

This is the HTML and JavaScript I'm using:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="toggle-zoom">
    <a href="#" class="noclick zin">Zoom In</a>
    <a href="#" class="noclick zout active">Zoom Out</a>                        
</div>  

<table data-filter="#filter-logos" class="footable">
    <thead>                         
        <tr>
            <th data-sort-ignore="true">Thumbnail</th>
            <th data-sort-ignore="true" title="Sort list">Description</th>
            <th title="Sort list">File Name</th>
            <th title="Sort list">File Type</th>
            <th data-type="numeric" title="Sort list">File Size</th>
            <th data-sort-ignore="true">Download</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="txt-center img-cell">
                <a href="#" class="noclick zoom-trigger link-cell" title="Zoom"><img src="http://placebear.com/g/800/200" alt="" class="tn small"></a>
            </td>
            <td>Logo  horizontal</td>
            <td>logo-h.eps</td>
            <td>EPS</td>
            <td class="txt-right">10KB</td>
            <td class="txt-center p0">
                <a href="#" class="noclick db ir link-cell download" title="Download">Download</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="txt-center img-cell">
                <a href="#" class="noclick zoom-trigger link-cell" title="Zoom"><img src="http://placebear.com/g/800/201" alt="" class="tn small"></a>
            </td>
            <td>Logo  horizontal</td>
            <td>logo-h.eps</td>
            <td>EPS</td>
            <td class="txt-right">10KB</td>
            <td class="txt-center p0">
                <a href="#" class="noclick db ir link-cell download" title="Download">Download</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="txt-center img-cell">
                <a href="#" class="noclick zoom-trigger link-cell" title="Zoom"><img src="http://placebear.com/g/800/202" alt="" class="tn small"></a>
            </td>
            <td>Logo  horizontal</td>
            <td>logo-h.eps</td>
            <td>EPS</td>
            <td class="txt-right">10KB</td>
            <td class="txt-center p0">
                <a href="#" class="noclick db ir link-cell download" title="Download">Download</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//Zoom
$('.zoom-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass('small');
    $(this).toggleClass('shrink');
});

    //Zoom In
    $('.zin').click(function(){
        $('.zoom-trigger').addClass('shrink');
        $('.tn').removeClass('small');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

    //Zoom Out
    $('.zout').click(function(){
        $('.zoom-trigger').removeClass('shrink');
        $('.tn').addClass('small');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

/*Active correct zoom button when all thumnails have been clicked*/
/*
$('a.zoom-trigger.shrink').length(function(){
  $('.zin').toggleClass('active');
  $('.zout').toggleClass('active');
});
*/

//Prevents default action of links
$('.noclick').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Again, here's a ***[Demo in Codepen](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/vFzwA)***.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really just want to "switch" the active state of the zoom in and zoom out buttons because you could have a mixture of zoomed in and zoomed out images so they're neither all zoomed in or all zoomed out. Instead, you can create a "zoomed" count and check if it's 0 or equal to the `.zoom-trigger` length to determine the button state.

```
(function($) {
  // cache as many selectors as possible to avoid 
  // re-querying the DOM every time a button is clicked
  var $zoomToggle = $('.zoom-trigger'),
      $zoomIn = $('.zin'), 
      $zoomOut = $('.zout'),
      $tn = $('.tn'),
      total = $zoomToggle.length,
      zoomed = 0;

  function zoomToggleClick() {
    var $button = $(this),
        isIn = $button.hasClass('shrink');

    $button
      .toggleClass('shrink')
      .find('img')
        .toggleClass('small');

    // increase or decrease 
    // zoomed count appropriately
    zoomed += isIn ? -1 : 1;
    updateZoomInOutButtons();
  }

  function zoomInOutClick() {
    var isIn = $(this).hasClass('zin');

    $zoomToggle.toggleClass('shrink', isIn);
    $tn.toggleClass('small', !isIn);

    // we max out the zoomed count if
    // they've clicked zoom all or reset
    // it if they've zoomed out all images
    zoomed = isIn ? total : 0;
    updateZoomInOutButtons();
  }

  function updateZoomInOutButtons() {
    $zoomIn.toggleClass('active', (zoomed === total));
    $zoomOut.toggleClass('active', (zoomed === 0));
  }

  $zoomToggle.click(zoomToggleClick);
  $zoomIn.click(zoomInOutClick);
  $zoomOut.click(zoomInOutClick);

  $('.noclick').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Jenna, when I created my initial JavaScript to handle each thumbnail zoom state, everything worked exactly as you describe it, meaning: If I had a combination of zoomed in and zoomed out images, I could click on the 'inactive' button and all images would 'obey' the action, while images on the same state as the inactive button would remain unchanged. Check out my initial demo again if you'd like: http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/vFzwA. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see what you're saying Jenna: Once there's a mix of zoomed in and zoomed out thumbnails the Zoom buttons should be 'inactive', because the buttons represent a single state for ALL thumbnails. Once a thumbnail is different from the rest, the Zoom buttons need to represent the possibility of activating either state. Never thought of seeing it like this. On top of this your solution is more efficient with DOM manipulation... (continues below)

Comment: ...My next step was to go to [CodeReview on Stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to ask about optimizing the above code. Your solution saves me this step as well. Thanks for your help as well. BTW, here's an ***[Upadated Demo in Codepen](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/qbtFK)*** (Click the Run button on the JavaScript container)

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
if($(".small").length==0)
   {
     //all are zoomed in
     $(".zin").addClass("active");
     $(".zout").removeClass("active");
   }
   else if($(".small").length==$(".zoom-trigger").length)
   {
      $(".zin").removeClass("active");
      $(".zout").addClass("active");
   }
```

**CodePen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Efldb

Comment: Hanlet, your solution works great but only if I have **exactly** 3 elements. The amount of elements the table is going to hold is unknown, I just happened to use three in the demo. Thanks.

Comment: You just count your .zoom-trigger elements, and that should give you the total. Try again.

Comment: Right on Hanlet! Exactly what I needed. I need to think about these concepts a bit better: *If zero items, do this. Else, do this taking this into consideration*. This is what's hard for my when doing JS. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Ricardo - This is not a very efficient solution as you will be re-querying the DOM every time a button is clicked to get $('.small').length (not to mention .zin, .zout and .zoom-trigger) which is a big no no for performance. Try to avoid querying the DOM wherever possible. My "zoomed" count solution below would be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @Jenna Hmm, I see. Yes, I've heard about avoiding re-querying the DOM many times before but since I'm not a JS guru I just create vanilla scripts like the one you see above at the expense of performance, but I don't have another choice... until the solution you provided. Read my comment on your post. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

```
//Zoom
$('.zoom-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass('small');
    $(this).toggleClass('shrink');
});

    //Zoom In
    $('.zin').click(function(){
        $('.zoom-trigger').addClass('shrink').children('.tn').removeClass('small');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

    //Zoom Out
    $('.zout').click(function(){
        $('.zoom-trigger').removeClass('shrink').children('.tn').addClass('small');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

//Active correct zoom button when all thumnails have been clicked
/*
$('a.zoom-trigger.shrink').length(function(){
  $('.zin').toggleClass('active');
  $('.zout').toggleClass('active');
});
*/

//Prevents default action of links
$('.noclick').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

DEMO:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mobKI

*NOTE: HAVE TO CLICK RUN IN JS FRAME FOR IT TO WORK USING CODEPEN!

Comment: Did you click the `run` button in the JS frame?